# Screenhot not able to capture shadow why?

Tags: android

Android Material card view shadow is removed when taking screenshot programatically as my background is white

** This is the code fragment to take screenshot**

```
View v1 = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
```